# Java break; won't work is intended... What is wrong with this structure?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, break

I want only the while loop to start over if the if condition inside is true.
In my book this is achieved with breaking the loop, to let it start over.
Problem with this code is: The break does nothing but stopping the while loop. If the if condition is true, nothing gets repeated. The method returns the value of x and it is over.
How can I get the while loop repeat if the if condition is met, in this example?
Thank you :)

```
public int example() {
for() {
    if() {
    //code
    }else{
    z=0;
        while (z==0) {
        //code
            if() {
                //code
                break;
            }else{
                z=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
return x;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `continue` instead of `break`?

Comment: Ok, thx :D that seems to work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here break; keyword is breaking the whole while loop if condition is true. And as the code has nothing else to execute after while loop has ended, the code returns 'X'.
I suppose that is not what you want.

1. You can either use continue keyword instead of break.
2. Or you can consider refactoring a method out of:

```
//code
if() {
    //code
    break;
}else{
    z=1;
}
```

like below:

```
public boolean condtionalRepeat(){
   //code
   if() {
       //code
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

and the code will look like:

```
public int example() {
for() {
    if() {
        //code
    }else{
        //code
        while (condtionalRepeat()) {
        //code
        }
    }
}
return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional comment on the original code: if this is accurate:

```
    while (z==0) {
    //code
        if() {
            //code
            break;
        }else{
            z=1;
        }
    }
```

then it collapses to

```
    //code
        if() {
            //code
        }else{
            z=1;
        }
```

The loop never loops. The first time through (in the original code) either the 'if' condition is satisfied, or it is not satisfied.

If satisfied, we end with a 'break' out the loop.

If not satisfied, we set z to 1, then loop to evaluate the 'while' condition, which terminates the loop.

Either way the loop executes once only.